# Excel 2013 If Function calculates True when condition is not met

Tags: microsoft-excel-2013

`=IF(I12="Y", J12*K$11, 0)`

But, if `I12` is blank, it calculates `J12*K$11` anyway.

I've tried text, general and number **formats** for `I12`.  This calculation works as a test in a new worksheet.  J12 is a link to a separate workbook.

Comment: Cannot reproduce. And you say it works fine in a new workbook (or worksheet?), just not the current one? Do you have auto-calculate on? Were the cells previously "y", but were changed? Try pressing `F9` and see if that does anything.

Comment: Yes, I tested a formula in a new worksheet for the "Y" to see if it would return a 0 if I12 was blank.  The formula in the real worksheet works if I12 is not left blank.  If I12 = "N" it returns a 0.

Comment: It was a new workbook...a whole new file

Comment: What if you copy your worksheets to a new workbook? Do they start to work then?

Comment: I started to try that, but the real worksheet is complex and J12 is a link to a completely different workbook.  I'd like to leave cells in Col I blank, but I can live with making it work by adding an "N" to get the correct outcome.  I had not seen this happen before and wondered if it was an option on the formulas tab.  Calculate Options is automatic, so that isn't it. go figure.

Comment: Are you copying by right click, copy, new workbook? What about saving the file as a new copy?

Comment: Ok I just tried the right click, copy paste into a new workbook and it worked!  Saving file under a different name didn't work.  Thank you Raystafarian!

Comment: Sounds like the workbook got corrupted, not entirely sure *how* that happened.

Comment: Me neither, but thank you again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the workbook you're working in got corrupted.

Try copying the worksheets to a new workbook by right clicking the sheet tab name, "Move or copy", new book. Then save that as the new working copy.